# Activity leaves a blank white screen after applying slide out animation on it

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, splash-screen

I am making a Weather app with a splash screen on it.

When, I start the app, I start the ViewPager that I have, and after that, in the ViewPager, I immediately start the SplashScreen. The splash screen stays still until I receive the weather information. After that, I apply a slide_out animation on the elements in the splash screen, as well as on the main LinearLayout container in the view.

I do this because I want to achieve a smooth slide out animation on the splash screen, like it's going away from the screen, through the bottom of the phone, smoothly revealing the main ViewPager behind.

The problem is that I can see the main LinearLayout container sliding down, but it leaves behind a semi-transparent screen until I call finish on the SplashScreen activity.

Can anyone help me with this?

Here is the SplashScreen:

[image]

Here is the SplashScreen animating:

[image]

Here is the SplashScreen after the animation has ended:

[image]

It stays like that until I call finish() on the SplashScreen. I want to slowly reveal the activity started behind.

**SplashScreenActivity.java:**

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Bind(R.id.image)
ImageView imageView;
@Bind(R.id.textView)
TextView textView;
@Bind(R.id.container)
LinearLayout container;

RotateAnimation rotateAnim;

BroadcastReceiver releaseAnimationReceiver;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);


    releaseAnimationReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.hasExtra("releaseAnimation")) {
                Log.e("Splash", "receivedBroadcast");
                //rotate(180);
                rotateAnim = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 180,
                        RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                        RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

                rotateAnim.setDuration(500);
                rotateAnim.setFillAfter(true);
                rotateAnim.setFillEnabled(true);
                rotateAnim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        imageView.setRotation(180);
                        Animation slideAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(SplashScreenActivity.this, R.anim.slide_out);

                        slideAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                                finish();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                            }
                        });

                        textView.startAnimation(slideAnimation);
                        imageView.startAnimation(slideAnimation);
                        container.startAnimation(slideAnimation);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                    }
                });
                imageView.startAnimation(rotateAnim);
                //rotateAnim.start();
            }
        }
    };

    this.registerReceiver(releaseAnimationReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.iancuio.weathy"));
}

private void rotate(float degree) {

    //rotateAnim.start();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    this.unregisterReceiver(releaseAnimationReceiver);
}
}
```

**SplashScreenActivity.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context="com.iancuio.weathy.ui.splash.SplashScreenActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_height="150dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="TEXT"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**slide_out.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillEnabled="true"
    android:fillAfter="true">
    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:toYDelta="100%p" />
</set>
```